# OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'path/bert-base-cased'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to load simple transformers NER model from my local path where I downloaded the Bert base cased model, I am not able to figure out why it is giving tokenizer error.
[image: Here is my line of code and problem please help me to find the solution]

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit, and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output.

Comment: Please show us the content of your directory. [Do not upload screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), nobody likes them. Better post the code and error messages directly as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.